# How to group taxonomy terms by their parent when using term reference field?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

Is there a way to group taxonomy terms by their parent name(as fieldsets) for term reference field in content creation?

For example: Cat#1 as parent and subCat#1, subCat#2 as children should be shown as a fieldset with Cat#1 as legend(and thus unselectable) and subCat#1 & subCat#2 should be shown in this fieldset.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Taxonomy Super Select](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_super_select) does what you want for Drupal 6, but there's no Drupal 7 version available.

However, the module page recommends the [Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](http://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) module to do the same thing

> This module provides an expandable tree widget for the Taxonomy Term Reference field in Drupal 7. This widget is intended to serve as a replacement for Drupal's core Taxonomy Term Reference widget, which is a flat list of radio buttons or checkboxes and not necessarily fit for medium to large taxonomy trees.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [Hierarchical Select Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) It is highly configurable.

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a
>   greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.

Check out a demo here http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select/taxonomy